# Add Textfields on GridPane

Tags: javafx

I want to add `TextField`s to a `GridPane` on every button click. When the user presses `btn2` two new `TextField`s are added to the `GridPane`. My code is:

```
btn2.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        grid1.add(new TextField(), 0, b);
        grid1.add(new TextField(), 1, b);
        b = b + 1;
    }
});
```

But I cannot get data from `TextField` or call the `setPromptText` method since the `TextField` has no name. Like if a `TextField`’s name is `tf1`. I can use

```
tf1.setPromptText("From");
```

Here it can not be done. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Do you want to set the _PromptText_ within your _handler_ or later external? If it's in the handler, you could do sth. like 
`TextField txt1 = new TextField();
 txt1.setPromptText("Test prompt");
 grid1.add(txt1,0,b);`

Answer (score 2):

## Placing the `TextField` in a suitable data structure

Example: `List<TextField[]>`

(Assuming you only add fields and change `b` nowhere else.)

#### Storing the fields

```
List<TextField[]> textFields = ...

btn2.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        TextField tf1 = new TextField(), tf2 = new TextField();
        grid1.add(tf1,0,b);
        grid1.add(tf2,1,b);
        textFields.add(new TextField[] {tf1, tf2});
        b=b+1;
    }
});
```

#### retrieving the fields

```
int row = ...
TextField[] tfs = textFields.get(row);
TextField tf1 = tfs[0];
TextField tf2 = tfs[1];
```

## Using the row and column properties of `GridPane`

[`GridPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html) provides static methods to retrieve the column and row indices from it's children. You can use those to find the correct elements (if you have only added one child per (column/row combination)):

```
int row = ...
TextField tf1 = null;
TextField tf2 = null;
for (Node node : grid1.getChildren()) {
    Integer nodeRow = GridPane.getRowIndex(node);
    if (row == (nodeRow == null ? 0 : nodeRow)) {
         Integer nodeColumn = GridPane.getColumnIndex(node);
         int i = nodeColumn == null ? 0 : nodeColumn;
         if (i == 0) {
             tf1 = (TextField) node;
         } else if (i == 1) {
             tf2 = (TextField) node;
         }
    }
}
```